# How to search and replace by comparing two PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this string where I've put all opening tags into `(array) $opened` and all closing tags into `(array) $closed`, like so:

```
'<div>
    Test
 </div>

 <div>
    <blockquote>
       <p>The quick</p>
       <blockquote>
          <p>brown fox <span>jumps <span>over <img src="#" /> the'
```

Results in these two arrays:

`$opened =`

```
array(8) {
  [0]=> string(3)  "div"         // Need removed
  [1]=> string(3)  "div"
  [2]=> string(10) "blockquote"
  [3]=> string(1)  "p"           // Need removed
  [4]=> string(10) "blockquote"
  [5]=> string(1)  "p"
  [6]=> string(4)  "span"
  [7]=> string(4)  "span"
}
```

`$closed =`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(3) "div"
  [1]=> string(1) "p"
}
```

I need to somehow say:

Find the first occurrence of `$closed[0]` (which is `"div"`) in the `$opened` array and remove it from the `$opened` array, then repeat until all `$closed` tags (`"div` and `"p"`) have been removed from the top of `$opened`.

Comment: Are you using the same snippet I gave in the other question? :p

Comment: No, meder. I will use / learn DOM stuff later. =) I have my own, very specific, RegEx which I use that is similar to your suggestion without the DOM.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Some kind of markup parsing?

Comment: Have you looked at it though? I would highly recommend using it instead of this. Trust me, DOM isn't really all that hard, and would be far easier than doing what you're trying to do now.

Comment: I am closing dangling tags, as shown in the string above. My regex is solid... e.g. <(a|div|p|blockquote|etc)\b .

Comment: What does your step 4 mean? Are you closing all <div>'s with one </div>?

If you are parsing HTML, then you should match closing tags with open ones as you go, not in the end. Create a stack of open tags, and if you find </div> look for the last <div> in $openTags and pop it from the stack.

Comment: As many have insisted, regex is not the way to deal with parsing HTML, plus it's harder than the DOM method I suggested. Can you take a look at it and try it instead? Comment on my answer if you have specific questions.

Comment: I will learn the DOM stuff, but *ahem* between you and me, I already have five other functions which rely on my Tidy RegEx which I'd really like to implement with the "close dangling tags" problem. When I have more free time, I'll reference your posts to learn the DOM stuff.

Comment: C'mon, confess: you're just posting such a question in order to provoke [bobince](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince), right? :)

Comment: Lol! =) I wish. I LOVE his reply.

Comment: To have at least some kind of parser, I would do the following: Split the input at the tags while preserving them (see `preg_split`’s _PREG\_SPLIT\_DELIM\_CAPTURE_). Then iterate the parts, put the opening tags on a stack and see if there is a corresponding closing tag and vice versa. If the opening and closing tags match, remove the opening tag from the stack. Doing so you can find mismatches of opening/closing tags and remove them or add the counterpart at the right position.

Comment: @Gumbo, excellent advice. If that was an answer, I'd `++` it.

Comment: @Bart: Maybe I’ll post an implementation for that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps someone. This is what I came up with:

```
<?php

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_closed; $i++ )
    {
        unset ( $opened[ array_search( $closed[ $i ], $opened ) ] );
    }

?>
```

I also came up with a `for` loop which worked, but you had to manipulate the `$opened[$i]` and `$closed[$n]` independently, and it was a bit more code, so I ultimately decided on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this will remove the first instance of the thing you are looking for.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$opened_tags = array("div", "div", "blockquote", "p", "blockquote", "p", "span", "span");
$closed_tags = array("div", "p");

$find = "div";

$size = sizeof($closed_tags);
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    if($closed_tags[$i] == $find){
        unset($closed_tags[$i]);
        break;
    }
}

echo "closed_tags with empty spaces: ".print_r($closed_tags, true)."<br /><br />";

$closed_tags = array_values($closed_tags);
echo "closed_tags array indexed correctly: ".print_r($closed_tags, true)."<br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from your question, but if your aim is to clean up a snippet of html code, why not simply use the HTMLTidy extension?

[Tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/761)